# Printer spooler spoolsv.exe crashes after user logon

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, printing

I'm facing problem with printer spooler on `Windows 2008 R2`. After user logon via RDP with printer redirection, process `spoolsv.exe` crashes with error:

```
Faulting application name: spoolsv.exe, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7b4e7
Faulting module name: localspl.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7c718
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000062edf
Faulting process id: 0x2624
Faulting application start time: 0x01cdfe079e8452da
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\localspl.dll
Report Id: 7d043444-7bfd-11e2-9ca1-00155d016800
```

This error makes redirected printers in all terminal session offline.
Client is using Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

My bet would be one of the redirected printers using an incompatible, out-of-date or just plain malformed driver.  Try removing the all client's printers, then adding them back one by one, until you figure out which printer driver's causing the problem, then update or remove the problem driver.